# Pre-commit hook is not working | Husky and Lintstaged

Tags: node.js, typescript, husky, lint-staged

I'm trying to use typescript pre-commit Husky hooks with LintStaged, but when I do a commit, the pre-commit script is not running, I just receive the common git response after commits.
[image: git commit response]

**.huskyrc.json**

```
{
"hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
}
```

}

**.lintstagedrc.json**

```
{
"*.ts": [
    "eslint 'src/**' --fix",
    "npm run test:staged"
]
```

}

**My file structure**

[image: File structure picture]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The another way of doing it is adding the scripts to the package.json file.

```json
// package.json

"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "eslint 'src/**' --fix",
      "npm run test:staged"
    ],
}
```

Comment: does this go in the root of the doc? Thanks,D.

Comment: yes. package.json which is in the root directory